# how to add class to button by using appendChild?

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild

i have created a button like this

```
var btn=document.createElement('BUTTON');
var t=document.createTextNode("X");
btn.appendChild(t);
x.appendChild(btn);
```

how can i add class to this button?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by using `.appendChild()`, but rather by setting the [`.className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) on the created element itself:

```
btn.className = "myclass";
```

Or if you don't care about older browsers, you can use [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList):

```
btn.classList.add("myClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

- with **jQuery**:

  ```
  $(btn).addClass('your-class');
  ```

  (see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/))
- without jQuery:

  ```
  btn.className = 'your-class';
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
btn.className = btn.className + "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(btn).css('font-weight','bold') or $(btn).addClass('className');
```

all is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try `btn.className` after `createElement`

```
var btn=document.createElement('BUTTON');
btn.className = "CLASS_NAME";
var t=document.createTextNode("X");
btn.appendChild(t);
x.appendChild(btn);
```